# efficiently make an all-by-all co-incidence tibble from an incidence tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr, tibble

I have a tibble that encodes which people like which foods.  There are ~3M rows, ~92k people, and ~2k foods.  I have calculated how popular each food (what % of people like it).  From that I have calculated how popular each pair of foods should be (prob of liking food 1 times prob of liking food 2).  Now I want to calculate how popular each pair of foods actually is, but I've tried a few ways and Rstudio crashes each time. So, I think I need to find a more efficient (maybe from a memory perspective) means of doing this.  Here's how I've done it. I apologize it's a lot of code, but I don't believe there are any unnecessary steps and I've tried to use good names so it's clear what each bit does.

```
library(tidyverse)
lu <- compose(length, unique)

set.seed(37212)

num_people <- 92000
num_foods <- 2000
num_prefs <- 3e6

person <- sample(x = num_people, size = num_prefs, replace = TRUE)
food <- sample(x = num_foods, size = num_prefs, replace = TRUE)

tibble(person = factor(person, ordered = TRUE),
       food = factor(food, ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
    distinct() ->
    food_prefs

stopifnot(lu(food_prefs$person) == num_people)
stopifnot(lu(food_prefs$food) == num_foods)

food_prefs %>%
    group_by(food) %>%
    summarise(p = n()/num_people) %>%
    print() ->
    food_popularities

food_popularities %>% 
    mutate(food1 = food,
           food2 = food) %>% 
    expand(food1, food2) %>% 
    filter(food1 < food2) %>%
    print() ->
    food_pairs
    
food_pairs %>% 
    inner_join(food_popularities, 
               by = c('food1' = 'food')) %>% 
    inner_join(food_popularities, 
               by = c('food2' = 'food'),
               suffix = c('1', '2')) %>% 
    mutate(p_joint = p1*p2) %>% 
    print() ->
    pairwise_popularity_expected

food_prefs %>% 
    group_by(food) %>% 
    summarise(person_list = list(person)) %>% 
    print() ->
    food_liker_lists


# the line here that starts with 'mutate' is what crashes my computer

food_pairs %>% 
    inner_join(food_liker_lists, 
               by = c('food1' = 'food')) %>% 
    inner_join(food_liker_lists, 
               by = c('food2' = 'food'),
               suffix = c('1', '2')) %>% 
    mutate(joint_list = map2(person_list1, 
                             person_list2, 
                             intersect),
           num_joint = map_int(joint_list, length))
```

I also tried using the `wider` package:

```
library(widyr)

pairwise_count(tbl = food_prefs, item = person, feature = food)
```

and was met with:

Error in m %*% t(m) :
Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_ssmult.c, line 222

Answer (score 1):

I think your best best is to use a sparse matrix instead of dense, e.g. the `Matrix` package. The sparse matrix is very memory efficient, which allows you to compute the adjacency matrix (co-occurence of foods, or people if you reverse the operation). Then you can deconstruct the matrix to a pairwise list.

```
A <- spMatrix(ncol = length(unique(food_prefs$person)),
              nrow = length(unique(food_prefs$food)),
              j = as.numeric(factor(food_prefs$person)),
              i = as.numeric(factor(food_prefs$food)),
              x = rep(1, nrow(food_prefs)))
rownames(A) <- levels(factor(food_prefs$food))
colnames(A) <- levels(factor(food_prefs$person))

adj <- A %*% t(A)
food_pairs <- data.frame(food1=rownames(adj)[row(adj)],food2=colnames(adj)[col(adj)],num_joint=as.numeric(adj))
food_pairs <- food_pairs[food_pairs$food1 != food_pairs$food2, ]
head(food_pairs)
# food1 food2 num_joint
# 2   F10    F1        23
# 3  F100    F1        26
# 4 F1000    F1        25
# 5 F1001    F1        19
# 6 F1002    F1        27
# 7 F1003    F1        34
```

Answer (score 1):

It fits better if you only look at food combinations that actually occur together:

```
food_prefs %>%
  inner_join(food_prefs, by = 'person') %>%
  filter(food.x < food.y) %>%
  count(food.x, food.y)
```

```
# A tibble: 1,999,000 x 3
   food.x food.y     n
   <ord>  <ord>  <int>
 1 1      2         19
 2 1      3         21
 3 1      4         19
 4 1      5         22
 5 1      6         13
 6 1      7         21
 7 1      8         20
 8 1      9         22
 9 1      10        23
10 1      11        21
# … with 1,998,990 more rows
```